# python for loop changes type of list element

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to iterate over a list of objects (I called the class "Wort", the object has a position-attribute that matches the position in the temporary list in this case) and have a strange problem: When I access the second element, the class of the first element changes.

At first I create the list like so:

```
another_loop:
    w = Wort(zk, row.ts.index(zk), bibs.index(row.Bib))
    templ.append(w)
```

Then, when I iterate over the list "templ":

```
print("templ is of type", type(templ))
for wobj in templ:
    if wobj.position > 0:
        print("Element", wobj.position - 1, 
            "of templ is of type", type(templ[wobj.position - 1]))

    else:
        print("Element", wobj.position,
            "of templ is of type", type(templ[wobj.position]))
```

gives the following output:

```
templ is of type <class 'list'>
Element 0 of templ is of type <class '__main__.Wort'>
Element 0 of templ is of type <class 'method'>
```

So the first run of the for-loop is correct. The element at position 0 is of type

```
<class '__main__.Wort'>
```

But the second run shows a wrong type:

```
<class 'method'>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any hint!

Comment: Your indentation is all messed up. Please post the correct code.

Comment: how did you create `templ`?

Comment: @Barmar : the lines get to long - but the code works with this indendation - that's not the problem

Comment: @MooingRawr : I created an empty list and created Wort-objects and filled the list with "templ.append(wort)"

Comment: Are you sure this is the actual code? Your output would come from something like `type(templ[wobj.position].somefunction)`

Comment: Can't reproduce, I get `NameError: name 'templ' is not defined` instead.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Your sample output lists `Element 0` twice, which is very suspicious.

Comment: Sorry, actually I cannot extract the code, and when I rewrite a small example, it works as expected... The problem lies somewhere else obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it - much later the code... 
The elements of templ list have been overwritten deep down in the iteration...

Thanks @MooingRawr for pointing me in the right direction, that somehow the list must have been broken!